# Best way to have an ASP/.NET ajax driven page updated using flex/flash?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, flash, apache-flex

I have a mapping application written in a flex/flash app. This app is used primarily to get bounding coordinates for the currently visible data on the map. I want to put this in an ASP page that is using ajax to update search results. The search results are defined by the bounding coordinates. Basically these bounding coordinates are the search query. What is the best way to update this search with the current coordinates from the flex app? I am not sure of the best way to have flex interact with the web page.

How do I tell my ajax driven ASP .net page to update results based on data from the flex app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AS3 ExternalInterface class to communicate with JavaScript.

In AS3 :

```
private function sendData(boundingCoordinates:Object):void
{
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("sendDataToASP", boundingCoordinates);
    }
}
```

In JavaScript :

```
function sendDataToASP(boundingCoordinates)
{
   // doAJAXStuffWithBoundingCoordinates();
}
```

Comment: I read about this externalinterface and wasn't sure if this was the recommended way or if there were other options. I think this will work nicely however. :) Thank you.

Comment: This worked great. I marked it as solved. I got it all working as intended now. Thank you! For those that are interested Ill include the other half to this answer.  http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-refresh-an-aspnet-ajax-updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

Two ways the flex/flash app could interact with the web page or server is to connect to the hostingpage via javascript/jquery/ajax calls or to connect directly from flex/flash via a webservice.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to manipulate an already visible html page (preferably the page the flex app resides in).